# Compilation of nine short stories about each of the nine planets (Classic SciFi)?

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a collection of classic SciFi short stories with one chapter about each of the nine planets, but I can't find any reference to it.
Here is what I remember.

- Mercury: Takes place on the boundary between the dark and light side, and the sun is going to rise and fry everyone.
- Venus: When the characters go outside, they are surrounded by a reflective force field.  They also float on a lake of liquid mercury.
- Jupiter:  Ship descends to the surface, and remote controlled robot or lifeform encounters the natives.
- Saturn:  Ship lands on the surface and it is like an ocean.
- Neptune:  Hot air balloon like ship floats through the upper atmosphere and encounters jellyfish like creatures that are also floating around there.

I can't remember the stories for the rest of the planets.

Has anyone ever seen/read this compilation of nine short stories?

Comment: about how long ago did you read it?

Comment: My first thought was [The Planets](http://www.amazon.com/Planets-Byron-Preiss/dp/0553051091/) edited by Byron Preiss, which gave each planet a scientific chapter followed by a science fiction chapter, but googling the names of the science fiction chapters shown at the bottom of [this page](http://www.worldcat.org/title/planets/oclc/12421530), I don't think they match your descriptions (for example, the story about life in a future Venus colony can be found online [here](http://www.scripsit.com/BigDome.html)). Thought I'd mention just in case though.

Comment: @Hypnosifl  My first thought (since the OP did say **classic** sci-fi) was Wollheim's *Flight into Space*, but the stories don't match. Next I thought of the much less "classic" *Isaac Asimov's Solar System* but those stories don't match either.

Comment: The balloon creatures sound vaguely familiar, but I can't place it.

Comment: You are definitely mixing your stories and planets. The one you list as Venus is Varley's Retrograde Summer which is set on Mercury.

Comment: The Jupiter story could be Asimov's [*Victory Unintentional.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victory_Unintentional)

Comment: Another possibility is [*Isaac Asimov's Solar System,*](http://www.amazon.com/Isaac-Asimovs-Solar-System-Various/dp/0441006981) but again the stories don't seem to match.

Comment: Two more possibilities: [The Science Fictional Solar System](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?46566) and [Tomorrow's Worlds](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?301653).  I started writing up an answer on the first one but realized only one story was really a good match (Neptune)

Comment: @Organic Marble - "Retrograde Summer" can be read on google books [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=JinIy94fhA8C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA119), maybe Matt E can check and hopefully verify that this is the one he was remembering when he said "When the characters go outside, they are surrounded by a reflective force field. They also float on a lake of liquid mercury." (looking it over now, it does contain both reflective force fields that act as space suits on p. 122, and the characters swimming in a 'Quicksilver grotto' of liquid mercury on p. 126-127)

Comment: @Hypnosifl Yeah, it's unlikely to be anything else, and it's definitely set on Mercury, not Venus.  There is a Varley story with the reflective forcefield suits set on Venus, "In the Bowl", but no lakes of mercury.

Comment: Sorry, it was later decided that that book _really_ only has _eight_ chapters plus an appendix.

Comment: @Organic Marble -- Assuming that's the one, the list of places it's been published can be found [here](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50784). None look like anthologies devoted to all the planets (the closest is maybe 'Worldmakers', an anthology about terraforming, but the review [here](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/gardner-dozois/worldmakers/) suggests most of its stories are about Mars and Venus). It may be that Matt E is mixing up memories of a book about the planets with some other book that contained "Retrograde Summer".

Comment: The Neptune story is almost certainly A Meeting with Medusa, but that's Jupiter and also not in any known planetary collection.

Comment: [One Sunday In Neptune](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44495) features a balloon-like craft exploring Neptune, but there are no jellyfish.

Comment: The Jupiter story is most likely Asimov;'s "Victory Unintentional" but offhand I can't place the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a compilation of stories set on each planet (plus Earth's moon) called "Tomorrow's Worlds," edited by Robert Silverberg.  Among the stories are "Wait it Out" by Larry Niven, set on Pluto (an astronaut stranded on Pluto takes his suit off, to cryogenically freeze himself to wait for rescue--and his nervous system becomes a superconductor so he can still think while he's waiting), and "Desertion" by Clifford Simak (humans on Jupiter send out explorers onto the planet in the bodies of Jupiter's native life; none return, but for a very surprising reason).  Could this be the book you're looking for?

Comment: That is 100% it!
Tomorrow's Worlds, edited by Robert Silverberg.
Thank you Melvin. I just bought a copy.
A childhood friend of mine borrowed it when we were young, and he was asking if I remembered it. I'll gift it to him after I read it again.

Comment: @MattE - if this is the correct answer, please click the checkmark to accept it as the answer.  And...welcome back!

Answer (score 3):

Wow, thanks everyone.
I am definitely mixing up my stories and planets.
Is has been over 35 years since I last read this.

Retrograde Summer and A Meeting with Medusa are definitely two of the titles.
One might have been Call Me Joe (Jupiter?).

Found a reference to 'The Planets' 1985, Bantam on this site:
https://www.astrosociety.org/education/astronomy-resource-guides/science-fiction-stories-with-good-astronomy-physics-a-topical-index/#topic

and 'The Science Fictional Solar System'
http://www.asimovreviews.net/Books/Book208.html

Comment: I think you must be misremembering stories you read in different places as being part of a single collection, since the internet sf database is generally comprehensive and shows no overlap between [places Retrograde Summer was published](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50784) and [places A Meeting With Medusa was published](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56729). *The Planets* from 1985 was the one I mentioned in a comment earlier, I linked to a table of contents, and [here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Science_Fictional_Solar_System) one for the other collection.