# To whom does each of these lightsabers belong?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, lightsaber, object-identification, art

These lightsabers look like they're from the *Star Wars* films:
[image]
These lightsabers look like they're from the *Star Wars* non-film universe:
[image]

## To whom does each of these lightsabers belong?

Comment: One of these things is not like the others, one of these things just doesn't belong... can you tell which thing is not like the other... by the time I've finished this song.

Comment: Well, NOW they belong to me.  You mean before the...event?

Comment: Is that [Rey's staff](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111766/21267) at the top right?

Comment: I have names for 3 of them and am pretty close for 1, but I'm too lazy to do all of them.

Comment: That's Darth Maul (the first one), Asajj Ventress (the curvy one), Kylo Ren(...).  The spinny one (these are official names now) is the kind used by Inquisitors (see http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Inquisitorius)

Comment: __why the downvote?__

Comment: @RedCaio Some people (not me) just don't like "identify these objects" questions, and downvote them on principle. Don't take it personally :-)

Comment: Related: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8957/who-in-the-universe-am-i

Comment: @Mooz Yes... hence my first comment...

Comment: @randal'thor those people should just add [object-identification] to their ignored tags.

Comment: @randal'thor I've seen posts closed for asking **two** questions in one post; what do you do when there are more than two dozen?

Comment: @user14111 Perhaps it's comparable to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116343/compilation-of-nine-short-stories-about-each-of-the-nine-planets-classic-scifi) - a single query containing multiple related subitems to be identified? Of course, feel free to VTC if you think this is too broad though.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[image]

1. [Darth Maul](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Maul's_lightsaber) (Ep. I)
2. [Qui Gon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Qui-Gon_Jinn's_lightsaber) (Ep. I)
3. [Obi Wan's first](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi%27s_first_lightsaber/Legends) (Ep. I) or [second](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi%27s_second_lightsaber/Legends) (Ep. II)<sup>1</sup>
4. [Count Dooku](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dooku's_lightsaber) (Ep. I-III)
5. [Anakin's first](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker's_first_lightsaber) (Ep. II)
6. [Mace Windu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mace_Windu's_lightsaber) (Ep. I-III)
7. [Yoda](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda's_lightsaber) (Ep. I-III)
8. [Palpatine's gold](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Palpatine's_lightsabers) (Ep. III)
9. [Anakin's second;  Luke's first; Rey's first](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Skywalker%27s_lightsaber) (Ep. III-V; Ep. VII, Clone Wars)
10. [Obi Wan's third](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi's_third_lightsaber) (Ep. III-IV;  Clone Wars)
11. [Vader](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vader's_lightsaber) (Ep. IV-VI, Rebels)
12. [Luke's second](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker's_lightsaber) (Ep. VI)
13. [Kylo Ren](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kylo_Ren's_lightsaber) (Ep. VII)
14. [Rey's staff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111766/is-reys-staff-made-of-lightsabers) (Ep. VII)

[image]

15. [Ashoka's first](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ahsoka_Tano's_lightsaber) (Clone Wars)
16. [Grand Inquisitor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Grand_Inquisitor's_lightsaber) (Rebels)<sup>2</sup>
17. [Ezra Bridger's lightsaber/blaster combo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ezra's_lightsaber) (Rebels)
18. [Kanan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kanan's_lightsaber) (Rebels)
19. [Stormtrooper/Cuis clones](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stormtrooper_lightsaber) (A Two Edged Sword)
20. [Qu Rahn;  Kyle Katarn's first](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Qu_Rahn's_lightsaber) (Dark Forces)
21. [Yun](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yun's_lightsaber) (Dark Forces)
22. [Jerec](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/f/fb/Jerec-saber.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20070514211724) (Dark Forces)
23. [Kyle Katarn's third](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyle_Katarn%27s_third_lightsaber) (Jedi Knight)
24. [Mara Jade's first](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mara_Jade's_first_lightsaber) (Mara Jade)
25. [Mara Jades's second](http://www.queeky.com/artist/caiored)  (Mara Jade)
26. [Galen Marek](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galen_Marek's_lightsaber) (Force Unleashed)
27. [Starkiller](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starkiller's_lightsabers) (Force Unleashed)
28. [Gavren Debrek](http://www.queeky.com/artist/caiored)  (fan creation)

---

<sup>1</sup>[These](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi%27s_first_lightsaber/Legends) two lightsabers were [identical](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi%27s_second_lightsaber/Legends)

<sup>2</sup>This model was also carried by [other inquisitors](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_Imperial_Inquisitor), the [Fifth Brother](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fifth_Brother), the [Seventh Sister](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Seventh_Sister).  Thanks to Rogue Jedi for mentioning that it was carried by more than one character.

*Thanks to Jason Baker for 2, 3, 5, 15, 18, 20, 21*

*Thanks to Red Caio and Mooz for 19 and 25, and 28*

Comment: 2 is Qui-Gon, 3 is Obi-Wan's first (from *Phantom Menace*), 5 is Anakin's first (from *Attack of the Clones*)

Comment: 15 is Ahsoka, pretty sure 18 is Kanan. 20 might be [Qu Rahn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Qu_Rahn%27s_lightsaber). Pretty sure 21 is [Yun](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yun%27s_lightsaber)

Comment: @JasonBaker - Dammit, I saw Kanan but didn't recognize it because the photo I found had a gold shroud.

Comment: About #16, it should perhaps be noted that it is an identical design used by all Inquisitors. If you want a single person, than the Grand Inquisitor would be most accurate.

Comment: Thanks so much for the excellent answer! I'm curious as to how you went about finding them; what worked the best for you?

Comment: @RedCaio   I recognized almost all of the movie sabers immediately.  I also knew the spinning one and blastersaber from other questions.  The rest were either given to me or required a ton of digging.

Comment: @RedCaio - at the end, I was just reading wookieepedia articles and clicking on the name of every force user, then googling that name plus "lightsaber".  It was HARD.

Comment: @RedCaio - Incidentally, 19, 25, and 28 were by far the hardest to find.  Now that I know you made the picture, can you confirm that everything I wrote is correct?

Comment: I drew these in my free time. You got them all correct (except 28, which I edited to be correct). 28 is a lightsaber that I designed myself, it belongs to Gavren Debrek, a character I created while playing a Star Wars Role-Playing Game. So 28 is a "fan creation" that isn't canon or legends. :) I'm super impressed that you got everything correct and so fast too! You've got mad skills.

Comment: Neat to see them all like that.  So Anakin's saber in Episode II was a darker blue color than most blue sabers?  Can't say I ever noticed that.